# Loading Growl in my Mac app: Unable to read symbols

Tags: objective-c, macos, macruby, growl

I am trying to load Growl so I can use it in my Mac app, but I keep getting this error:

```
warning: Unable to read symbols for @executable_path/../Frameworks/Growl.framework/Versions/A/Growl (file not found)
warning: Unable to read symbols from "Growl" (not yet mapped into memory).
```

What does this mean and how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there is a step I missed. Don't forget to [do these steps](http://growl.info/documentation/developer/implementing-growl.php):

1. Download the Growl framework from the [Downloads](http://growl.info/downloads#devdownloads) page.
2. Copy the Growl framework to your application's project folder (or any subdirectory of it).
3. Add the Growl framework to your project, making sure that all the relevant target checkboxes are checked. The header files in the framework use UTF-8 encoding.
4. **Add a Copy Files phase** to your application's target (App target > Build Phases > Add Build Phase).
5. Get Info on the Copy Files phase.
6. Set the destination to “Frameworks”, with no subpath (clear the field).
7. Drag the framework from the group tree into the Copy Files phase.

From now on, your application will compile and link using the Growl framework inside its bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the latest version of Growl installed on your machine, as well as the latest framework (build the Growl framework project that your app is using).

Comment: i downloaded the latest (1.3.1 SDK) from their website, copied `Growl.framework` into my project and it's not working

Comment: According to their documentation, the latest version does not even need Growl installed in order for it to work.